# Python + PostgreSQL : [Id] + row IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, postgresql, anaconda

I'm new with working in Python 3.7 (anaconda) + PostgreSQL. The task is to put data into the PostgreSQL database, but I'm keep receiving this thing:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gshn/PycharmProjects/StatsWithPandasRSQL/Pandas/load_data_to_postgres.py", line 37, in <module>
    [Id] + row
IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I fix it?
The code itself:

```
import psycopg2
import csv

conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost port=5433 dbname=gshn     user=postgres password=secret")
cursor = conn.cursor()

query = """
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS adult_data (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    age INTEGER,
    workclass VARCHAR,
    fnlwgt INTEGER,
    education VARCHAR,
    education_num INTEGER,
    marital_status VARCHAR,
    occupation VARCHAR,
    relationship VARCHAR,
    race VARCHAR,
    sex VARCHAR,
    capital_gain INTEGER,
    capital_loss INTEGER,
    hours_per_week INTEGER,
    native_country VARCHAR,
    salary VARCHAR
    )
"""
cursor.execute(query)
conn.commit()

with open('/Users/gshn/PycharmProjects/StatsWithPandasRSQL/Pandas/adult_data.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # Skip the header row
    next(reader)
    for Id, row in enumerate(reader):
        cursor.execute(
            "INSERT INTO adult_data VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
            [Id] + row
        )
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Without seeing the code that traceback refers to - it's pretty impossible to answer. Could you have a look at how to create a [mcve] and [edit] your question accordingly?

Comment: Code? The traceback itself gives us very little information to work with.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, just edited the question

Comment: Looks like your csv file does not supply enough cells in at least one of its rows. Empty trailing line maybe?

Comment: I can attach this csv for you to look through. I'm really new with this things and SQL in particular, so..

Comment: If the csv is not too big, you could. A better solution would be to wrap the `cursor.execute()` call in a [`try-except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) block waiting for `IndexError` and doing `print([Id] + row)` in the `except` part. That lets you see exactly the row(s) causing the error.

Comment: ok, I think I've fixed this. @shmee your advice helped me. thank you!